# How can I extract data from non-corrupted .rar parts?

Tags: windows-xp, rar, file-corruption

I have 15 RAR files with names like `part 1`, `part 2` etc. Usually when I extract them, it combines them all into one folder.

Now the the problem is: The first part is damaged and it is not extracting any further.

Is there any way to extract data from the remaining 14 files?

Answer (score 0):

You may try recovering your files using a tool like [this](http://www.rarfix.org/).

[image]

Here's the [direct download link](http://www.rarfix.org/download/RARFixerInstall.exe).

Comment: This is a bogus link, please remove it ASAP !